# forward port 3306 from firewalled machine to desktop using SSH?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, linux-networking, debian-lenny, ssh-tunnel

Here's the network setup:

Machine A (my PC) SSH 22 => Machine B (Linode with root access) SSH 21343 => Machine C (MySQL server).

I want to forward port 3306 from C through B to A, so I can use SQL Workbench on A to execute commands on C.

Note that C is only accessible over SSH port 21343 and only from B (we cannot change the firewall on C to open any more ports, but we can change its SSH settings).

Is this possible? I've read about tunnels and ProxyCommand. But I need a simple step-by-step example.

All machines are debian Lenny.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH tunneling and port forwarding](http://serverfault.com/questions/190854/ssh-tunneling-and-port-forwarding)

Comment: See the question I marked as a dupe, also see the man page for `ssh`, specifically the `-L` option.

Comment: The dupe question seems to only refer to two machines. I don't understand it.

Comment: @Moshie - Please **read the man page** as it explains how to use an intermediate machine (b) to forward ports exactly the way you wish.  See also Quanta's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

On the machine A:

```
ssh -L 3307:C:3306 user@B
```

This allocated a socket listen to port 3307 on A. And whenever a connection is made to this port, it is forwarded over ssh tunnel to C:3306.

You can then connect to MySQL server on C with:

```
mysql -u <user> -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

(127.0.0.1 to connect via TCP/IP instead of a socket)

---

> No, I cannot connect to MySQL on C from B. Only SSH listening on 21343
>   is open to B.

If the firewall on C only allow to connect from localhost, something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

so, AFAIK, there is no way to do this. If you try to connect over ssh tunnel, you will get the below errors:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Comment: Only machine B can talk to machine C, and only over SSH port 21343

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL server on C from B?

Comment: Hi Quanta, thanks for the follow-up. No, I cannot connect to MySQL on C from B.  Only SSH listening on 21343 is open to B.

Comment: Please check out my above answer.

Answer (score 1):

~/.ssh/config on machine A looks like this:

```
Host C
  ProxyCommand ssh -q B nc %h %p
  LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306
  Port 21343

Host B
  Hostname X.X.X.X  (ip of host B)
```

Then on A `ssh C`

and in another terminal on A run `mysql -h localhost`  This will connect you to mysql on C over the ssh port forward.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something along the lines of http://sourceforge.net/projects/portfwd/ on machine B, possibly listening on something other than TCP 22 so SSH can remain on its standard port for machine B.